# SCSS/SASS Not loading custom styles

Tags: compilation, sass

Dove into SASS this morning for the first time, and I am impressed with the potential...but I am having a slight issue.

(Using Gumby Responsive framework)

So far, I can't seem to get the _custom.scss to compile with everything else.

```
// Your custom SCSS should be written here...
$color: #0066a6;

body{
    background: $color;
}
```

I added the above to the _custom.scss, went to the command prompt, typed "compass compile" and it returned "unchanged sass/gumby.scss"
I also tried "compass compile sass/_custom.scss" and all that did was create a "custom.css" that (of course) was not showing up either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show us your compass_config.rb?

Comment: not exactly sure where that is...:|
did a search for "compass_config" and no files came up in the search (and that was a full computer search)

Comment: ...answer added below. sorry.
You know, no matter what I do, I always seem to get my wrist slapped for something on here.

Answer (score 1):

By using the `_` at the beginning of your stylesheet name, your using a sass partial. That tells sass to not create standalone stylesheet for `_custom.scss` at compile time.

Remove the partial to make sass create the sheet: ie. rename it to `custom.scss`

or keep the partial and import it into your main stylesheet with:

```
@import "custom";
```

Example, two sheets `_reset.scss` and `base.scss`:

```
/* _reset.scss */

html,
body,
ul,
ol {
  margin:  0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* base.scss */

@import 'reset';

body {
  font-size: 100% Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #efefef;
```

Here `_reset.scss` wont be compiled into its own standalone sheet ( because of the partial), but will be included in the base.scss sheet right before the body declartion ( because base.scss isnt a partial). The output would look like this:

```
/* base.scss */

html,
body,
ul,
ol {
  margin:  0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 100% Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #efefef;
```

Make sure your compass configuration is setup correctly. First initiate your project with:

```
compass create path/to/project --sass-dir=[your_sass_dir]
```

Then you'll have a config file called `config.rb`. It should look something like this:

```
# Location of the theme's resources.
css_dir         = "css"
sass_dir        = "sass"
fonts_dir       = "css/fonts"
extensions_dir  = "sass-extensions"
images_dir      = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
```

Comment: by default, the Gumby framework already imports the partials into a main scss file called gumby.scss
However I did try your suggestion of removing the partial and that did not work either.

Comment: did you add an import?

Comment: No, because it was already there. 
gumby comes with its own non-partial, and a list of partials in its scss directory(the equivalent of your base.scss above) (add the list of imports above)

Comment: Updated question above based on your update...
Created the new project, posted the config, as well as found the original gumby config.rb

Comment: do the paths in the grumpy config match the paths on your project? they look pretty generic.

Comment: yes. they match up. I don't get it, I followed the instructions on the Gumby documentation -- TO THE LETTER...I don't understand why it would not be working.

Comment: @Akel eveything seems to make sense. Is compass watching? if it is, i'll delete my answer so you can get more traffic.

Comment: interesting...check my solution above...was the weirdest thing. (editing my original question)

Answer (score 0):

Solution Found

Was the weirdest thing...opened the "gumby.css" (was a last ditch, "i'm getting super peeved" moment) hit select all -> delete -> save -> close

Then headed back to the command prompt, did the 'compass compile' command, and somehow voila...apparently I just needed to delete everything in the original gumby.css before continuing, because then it recreated the css file with the @import partials working.